# how to return upper value of node property with cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I got a question that I need to return the node property which should be uppercase, I read the neo4j manual and didn't find the way to do that, I noticed that the version 1.9 has upper function while I use is 1.7, for the other reason that I don't want to upgrade my neo4j, so is there any solution about this, thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Neo4J 1.7 does not have an `UPPER()` function, you will have to do the conversion in your own code before displaying the result.

Another (but ugly) solution would be to create a node property to hold the uppercased version of the string.

Comment: Thanks Werner, this is the only answer I got, anyway I have to think that Neo4j is a bad choice for me.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  Why can't you upgrade Neo4J?

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of neo4j you can do using `toUpper()` function